# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting Not Doing Basic Math Properly

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

TL;DR: Google Sheets conditional formatting is doing something weird, and I want to know how to make it do math properly.

I am trying to have a column of numbers that have a tinted background if their value is higher than the value of a specific other cell. I have a formula for this. It works flawlessly in many other places in this workbook. But in this location, it does this:

[image: Conditional Formatting comparing the values of multiple cells acting very strangely.]

So, apparently in this particular part of the sheet, both 1 and 2 are greater than 2?

I have cleared the formatting repeatedly, made the rule from scratch, and it still does this. The exact same rule works just fine comparing the top cell in column D with values below.

So, my question isn't (necessarily) how to highlight cells that have a larger value than another cell. My question is, what could be causing this weird behavior, and how do I fix it?

Comment: 1 Check for hidden characters inside the cells. 2 Verify that the cells you are comparing have the correct number formatting. 3 Try using  =D1>2 to see if it behaves as expected.

Comment: @Liontass Thank you for the comment! I actually didn't see it until after I figured it out, but your response should help people who have similar issues. I had already tried doing it compared to flat values, though. Same behavior. I am super curious what numbering format could cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Google Sheets had decided that the Automatic number type for some of the numbers (the rows below the first in the table) needed to be a different type than the top row. I wasn't seeing it because I had the numbers centered, but when I removed that formatting, I noticed that the top value aligned right, while the rest aligned left.

I have no way of knowing what number type had been applied, since they still listed as Automatic, but setting the entire column to integer (just a 0, no decimals) fixed the problem. I assume making them match in whatever manner would work.

Note that this issue persisted through several no-formatting wipes (I didn't realize the alignment thing was significant until now), so manually selecting number type was necessary, as this was apparently not so much a formatting issue as a data-mismatch one.

Still no clue why this occurred, but there's the way to diagnose and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try by locking the first cell.

```
 =$L1>$L$1
```

[image]